# Are как and вроде interchangeable when citing or listing things or examples of things?

Tags: словоупотребление, наречия

For example, in the following passage:

> Там паук ждёт, пока в лову́шку не попадётся небольшое насеко́мое вроде ба́бочки или стрекозы́.

¿Could this just as well be expressed as:

> Там паук ждёт, пока в лову́шку не попадётся небольшое насеко́мое как ба́бочка или стрекоза.

Comment: Can u replace "such as" with "as"?

Comment: @Anixx: I think you mean "such as" with "like" and yes, we can: ...insects such as butterflies and dragonflies, ...insects like butterflies and dragonflies.

Comment: no, I mean "such as" and "as".

Comment: No. But doesn't как also have the meaning "like" ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, `как` can't be used to equally replace `вроде`.  In this sentence, `вроде` means `such as`, and can be replaced with a clause beginning with `такое как`:

```
Там паук ждёт, пока в лову́шку не попадётся небольшое насеко́мое, такое как ба́бочка или стрекоза.
```

(note the case change here).